# Google Cardboard Unity VR- remove the need for alt key on mouse up/down

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Could anyone please tell me how to remove having to press **alt**-mouse up/down in unity google cardboard VR when testing on a PC ? I need my PC test VR app just to use the mouse in the regular FPS way. The mouse works fine for left and right but up down is mapped to pressing the alt-up/down key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer in EditorDevice.cs:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt))
```

comment this out and it works fine

Comment: Works in editor but the change doesn't affect desktop builds.